# Visual Code Formatting Error

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-code

Currently i have a "error" in my code formatting after updating vs code (1.15.1).
When i write a if statement and try to add the brackets i get something like this every time:

[image]

this also happens with for loops for example:

[image]

when i write a try catch block it doesn't happen which is kind of strange:

[image]

This are my current user settings:

[image]

the workspace settings are empty.
Am i missing out on something or is this a known bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug, see [#29390](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29390) (actually, it's considered a "feature-request" at the moment...). You probably started experiencing this because [the 1.15.0 release enabled the `editor.autoIndent` setting by default](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_auto-indentation).

The simplest workaround is to disable auto indentation in your `settings.json`:

```json
"editor.autoIndent": false
```

Alternatively, you could try changing the indentation rules for the language you're working with, but that involves messing with VSCode / extension sources.

Comment: well thanks for your suggestion, but its not working in my case with that simple setting. In javascript source code the error is still present but for some reason in c# and php code not. I guess i wait or probably downgrade until this gets fixed. I cant work with that kind of stuff

Comment: Hm.. have you tried the hack suggested by one of the commenters in that issue? That's for TS, not JS, but should be similar: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29390#issuecomment-315073944

Comment: actually its not worth it for me to spend more time on this issue. i thought maybe there is a fast solution for it. But it looks like it would take a while for the vs code team to release a bug fix. For now i went back to my working version. But thanks you for your help